# add Marker not working

Tags: mapbox

This is crazy, add marker doesn't seem to do what it suppose to do. Adding marker does nothing:

```
{
if(!isVisible())
return;

    mPinBitmapUtils.retrievePinBitmapAsync(getContext(), recommendation, new OnPinBitmapProcessed()
    {
        @Override
        public void onBitmapProcess(final Pin reco, PinType pinType, Map<String, String> directories)
        {
            if(!isVisible())
                return;

            recommendation.setName(pinType.getName());

            new AsyncTask<String, Void, PinMarkerOptions>()
            {
                @Override
                protected PinMarkerOptions doInBackground(String... strings)
                {
                    IconFactory iconFactory = IconFactory.getInstance(getContext());

                    Bitmap bitmap = Utils.getBitmapFromFile(getContext()
                            , new File(strings[0])
                            , (int) Utils.convertDpToPixel(48, getContext())
                            , (int) Utils.convertDpToPixel(48, getContext()));

                    Icon icon = iconFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap);

                    LatLng position = new LatLng();
                    position.setLatitude(recommendation.getLatitude());
                    position.setLongitude(recommendation.getLongitude());

                    PinMarkerOptions markerOption = new PinMarkerOptions();
                    markerOption.setPosition(position);
                    markerOption.setMetaData(recommendation.getJSON().toString());

                    if(icon != null)
                        markerOption.setIcon(icon);

                    return markerOption;
                }

                @Override
                public void onPostExecute(PinMarkerOptions marker)
                {
                   mMapboxMap.addMarker(marker);
                }

            }.execute(directories.get(Constants.BLUE_PIN));
        }
    });
}
```

Every time I called `addMarkers` or `addMarker` its not being shown. I checked the size of the `MapBox` map instance and it indeed show it increased in size. This happens especially when I remove a marker, or called `MapBoxMap#clear()`. Nothing happens afterwards.

I am using MapBox API v4.2.2.

Answer (score 0):

There is one problem with markers - you can't add them on top of your layers.
If that is a case, then you should use SymbolLayer for that purpose.

[Info about markers from documentation.](https://www.mapbox.com/help/markers/)

[Example of how use SympolLayer with BubbleLayout](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/blob/master/MapboxAndroidDemo/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxandroiddemo/examples/dds/InfoWindowSymbolLayerActivity.java) to create a marker with text inside.